Creating a new instance of an object crashes unity build but not editor
In my project in one specific mono behavior class when I try to create a new() instance of a non mono behavior class unity and the build version that I exported, freezes without any error but I don not get  any error in editor. Tried to get a debug.log out of it but cant get anything when it freezes and closes. I can get the debug.log before this call and next one never reaches.
private void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("AWAKE CALL");
    Debug.Log(new BluePrintItem.AICoreBlueprint().GetName());
    Debug.Log("AWake after");
}

Even when I try to create it with reflection and CreateInstance it doesnt work. I get "DEBUG 1" and "DEBUG 2" and "DEBUG 3" and nothing else!
private void InitTierCraftedList()
{
    Debug.Log("DEBUG 1");
    List<Type> craftedItems = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BluePrintItem)).GetTypes().ToList().
        Where(Thetype => Thetype.IsClass &&
        !Thetype.IsAbstract && Thetype.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BluePrintItem))).ToList();

    Debug.Log("DEBUG 2");
    Debug.Log(craftedItems.Count);

    foreach (var item in craftedItems)
    {
        Debug.Log("DEBUG 3");
        BluePrintItem target = (BluePrintItem)Activator.CreateInstance(item);
        int highestTier = 0;
        Debug.Log("DEBUG 342");
        foreach (var material in target.materialsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("DEBUG 4");
            if (material.GetItemTier() > highestTier)
            {
                highestTier = material.GetItemTier();
                Debug.Log("DEBUG 5");
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("DEBUG 6");
        switch (highestTier)
        {
            case 1: firstTierItems.Add(target.CraftedItemReference()); break;
            case 2: secondTierItems.Add(target.CraftedItemReference()); break;
            case 3: thirdTierItems.Add(target.CraftedItemReference()); break;
            case 4: forthTierItems.Add(target.CraftedItemReference()); break;
            default: Debug.LogWarning("CHECK HERE ASAP"); break;
        }
    }
}

Tried it on android and pc builds nothing changes.
Tried with Mono and IL2CPP nothing changes as well.
Disabled Code-Striping and nothing changed there too.
Didn't do any assembly changes or anything like that.
If anyone can help me this problem that would be appreciated!

Does BluePrintItem have any constructor?

Found the problem! I was calling A method in constructor and it was calling the load of addressables and the addressable is the main reason of this crash!
